# Is it possible to use browserify-css with factor-bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Let's say I have a directory setup like

```
app
 \ page1
   - page1.js
   - page1.css
 \ page2
   - page2.js
   - page2.css
 \ fancy-widget
   - fancy-widget.js
   - fancy-widget.css
 \ common
   - shared-utils.js
   - general-styles.css
```

and I want output like

```
- page1.js
- page1.css
- page2.js
- page2.css
- shared.js
- shared.css
```

where the "shared" js/css files contain the scripts/styles that are `require`d by both page1 and page2.

I'm able to use [`factor-bundle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/factor-bundle) to satisfy the javascript side of my requirement, but I haven't been able to make [`browserify-css`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-css) play nicely with it. I found the `onFlush` option for browserify-css, but it seems to be called for every js file that makes a css `require` call, as opposed to once per factored bundle file.

Is it possible to accomplish this "factor-bundle-css" functionality as described above?

Comment: @JensAlenius Yes I'm using node and a custom build script to call browserify w/ the factor-bundle and browserify-css plugins.

Comment: used to use browserify but switched to webpack. Webpack can do more than browserify. It very powerful and very popular

Comment: @JensAlenius thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that out

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding an alternative to `browserify-css`.

[`css-concatify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-concatify) claims that it

> Supports Factor-Bundle w/o any configuration changes.